# How to skip Selenium TestNG tests based on test environment

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a test that logs into an app and checks a few things but the login screen won't be present in all of the test environments. Login verification test would fail where there is no login screen, how can I overcome this by disabling/skip the login test based on the environment?

Also what I am not very clear is that these tests will be integrated with automated CI/CD pipeline. How the tests would know against what environment the test is run if there is no manual intervention. Sorry, there may be an obvious answer to this but I am a novice to automation and CI/CD.My test is written in Java, many thanks for your help

Comment: You need to pass parameters of env in which you are running .. n for skip you can use ignore attribute in testNG

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's 'out-of-box' Annotation transformer in TestNG with which You can implement `transform()` method and define the statement when `@Test` annotation on your test should be marked with `ignore=false` [TestNG doc.](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers)

But, this approach have one disadvantage - annotation transformer must be set in Your's 'test.xml' to use it.
When You don't use xml to build test DOM - then You can define Your own Annotation like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface EnvDependentIgnore {
String reason();
Environment env();
boolean skip();
}
```

Also You need to implement `IInvokedMethodListener` to read your annotation values before test invocation.

```
public class IgnoreTestListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult testResult) {
    Method method = iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(EnvDependentIgnore.class)) {
        if (//"your environment value"
                .equalsIgnoreCase(method.getAnnotation(EnvDependentIgnore.class).env().getValue()) &&
                method.getAnnotation(EnvDependentIgnore.class).skip()) {
            throw new SkipException(method.getAnnotation(EnvDependentIgnore.class).reason());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    // no need to implement
}
}
```

It's a bit messy approach, but it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very exact use case. In fact 2 similar use cases.

1. Skipping tests based on the defect status.
2. skipping tests based on the test environment.

even though they both sound same, implementation is slightly different.

for skipping tests based on environment, I had to use TestNG `IMethodInterceptor`

```
@Override
public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> testMethods, ITestContext context) {    

    //removeIf method returns a boolean if any of the item is removed
    boolean isTestRemoved = testMethods.removeIf(somePredicate);

    //if any item is removed, then there is a chance that we might get execption due to missing dependencies.
    testMethods.stream()
               .map(IMethodInstance::getMethod)
               .forEach(method -> method.setIgnoreMissingDependencies(isTestRemoved));

    return testMethods;
}
```

for skipping tests based on defect status, I had to use `IInvokedMethodListener`

More details are here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-skip-tests-based-on-test-environment/

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-automatically-skip-tests-based-on-open-defects/

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your test cases using TestNG groups. Tag your test cases with your environment data. So when you run your test cases you will specify which environment(ex. login env) you want to run using TestNG -groups options. It will only run those test cases which are tagged with the specified tag/gropus.

For more info on groups see https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches:

1. sort Your tests by class depending on environment.
2. sort by `@Test(groups = {"test"})`, `@Test(groups = {"production"})` and filter via (if using testNg testsuite.xml via parameter) here is xml example

   ```
       <!--server parameter-->
       <parameter name="file" value="/build.apk"/>
       <parameter name="server" value="LOCAL"/>
       <parameter name="device" value="emulator-5554"/>

        // with this as parameter and parse it in code//
       <parameter name="environment" value="TEST"/>

        // or via group filtration in testng //
       <groups>
           <run>
               <include name="production"/>
           </run>
       </groups>

       <packages>
           <package name="testing.android"/>
       </packages>
   </test>
   ```
3. create You own environment interface @Environment("production"), check this [article](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-split-junit-tests-in-a-continuous-integration-environment)
4. inject through environment/system variable in maven when run CI in let's say Jenkins via Maven eg:

   > mvn -Denv=production test

Hope this helps,